# GridView not showing new inserted row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a gridview and sqldatasource.
When I'm adding a new row in the gridview I need to refresh the page in order to see the new row.
The View state is enabled.

Is there anything I can do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call `DataBind()` on the relevant object (in your case it is probably the SqlDataSource, otherwise is generally the GridView).  Doing so should bring up your new record assuming the record actually did get added (you should verify this).

Reference: [Control.DataBind Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d)

Answer (score 0):

The `DataBind()` method of the GridView will reload the data.  It is especially useful when you are changing your selectStatement of the SqlDataSource as well. It is a good habit to use this after updating anything that is contained in your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Call `DataBind()` after inserting your new row.